# Converting ambiguous character string to POSIXct

Tags: r

I've got some printed date-time strings, and I'm struggling to understand why the following code doesn't work. I think I have misunderstood the purpose of the `format` option in `strftime`.

Can someone please explain why the following does not work, and suggest how I can convert these strings to a date-time format understood by R?

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~time, ~value,
  "Tue, Jan 28 2020 13:41:26", 1,
  "Tue, Jan 28 2020 13:41:07", 2,
  "Tue, Jan 28 2020 13:40:06", 3,
  "Tue, Jan 28 2020 13:39:04", 4
)

data %>% 
  mutate(
    # see ?strftime for the POSIX standard conversions used below
    time = strftime(time, format = "%a,%b %d %Y %T")
  )
```

Error message:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz = tz) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I don't think it's a locale issue, `Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_ALL")` yields:

```
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `mdy_hms` from `lubridate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
data %>%
     mutate(time = mdy_hms(time))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  time                value
#  <dttm>              <dbl>
#1 2020-01-28 13:41:26     1
#2 2020-01-28 13:41:07     2
#3 2020-01-28 13:40:06     3
#4 2020-01-28 13:39:04     4
```

---

`strftime` works on `Datetime`, object, here the `class` is `character`.   According to `?strftime`

> The format and as.character methods and strftime convert objects from the classes "POSIXlt" and "POSIXct" to character vectors.

```
data %>% 
     mutate(time  = as.POSIXct(time, format = '%a, %b %d %Y %T'))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  time                value
#  <dttm>              <dbl>
#1 2020-01-28 13:41:26     1
#2 2020-01-28 13:41:07     2
#3 2020-01-28 13:40:06     3
#4 2020-01-28 13:39:04     4
```